# trying to identify b-movie from 70's where people trying to escape something in desert are hit & bludgeoned by spiky plants

Tags: story-identification

I half watched this movie in downtown Los Angeles back in the 70's. All I could remember of this movie is that those spiky desert plants were swinging and whacking people to death. A few people were wandering in the desert. Can't even remember how they got there, but they were running from something and then the plants would just slam them in the face or chest or back!

Comment: Reminds me of [that one scene in HGTTG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZHj_YZQlUM), but the date is wrong.

Comment: Wasn't that every b movie in the 70s?

Comment: "those spiky desert plants" You mean [cactus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus) or something more exotic?

Comment: Not HGTTG and not cactus. Nothing exotic either. They are all over the desert here in Nevada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Meatcleaver Massacre](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076380/)" (1977)?

I don't know how I happened upon this one, but it IS late '70s, and it does appear to have scenes of plants whacking people. The plot involves a professor of the occult summoning a Celtic demon-god to avenge the murder of his family by four of his students while he lays in a hospital bed.

### Trailer

Comment: OMG!!! I really think this is the one! Thank you, thank you, thank you! I'm gonna have to watch this now to be sure! I think my search is over! This is one I never thought would get figured out and it was driving me crazy trying to remember. If this is NOT the one... I give up!

Answer (score 2):

"The Navy vs the Night Monsters"(1966)?

It has 'spiky' plant monsters that resemble the type of trees you mention. It certainly looks like a desert, even though it supposedly takes place on a South Pacific island because the majority of it was filmed at Vasquez Rocks Natural Park, California USA. Here is a trailer, and at 1:06 you can see the plant creatures looking like tree stumps marching through the desert.

Comment: Interesting to see all the different movies, but this is not the one. The plants weren't walking or moving forward. They stayed in place and were just whackin and swinging and hitting people as they happen to walk or run past them. It was also more like in the late 70's/early 80's maybe. thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Hmmm, I can't think what it could be. My only other guesses would be "The Revenge of Dr. X"(1970), or "Island of the Doomed"(1967)? I have only seen Island of the Doomed  but don't remember a desert.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *The Day of the Triffids*?

Comment: Can you add some details that show us _why_ it might be _The Day of the Triffids_?

Comment: Definitely not The Day of The Triffids.